# How can i handle Stream management duplicate record?

Tags: ios, objective-c, chat, openfire

- I am implementing XMPPStreamManagement **XEP-198** but my last message repeated multiple time

  ```
  _xmppStreamManagement = [[XMPPStreamManagement alloc] initWithStorage:[XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage new]];             
  // And then configured however you like.
  // This is just an example:
  _xmppStreamManagement.autoResume = YES;
  _xmppStreamManagement.ackResponseDelay = 0.2;
  [_xmppStreamManagement requestAck];
  [_xmppStreamManagement automaticallyRequestAcksAfterStanzaCount:3 orTimeout:0.4];
  [_xmppStreamManagement automaticallySendAcksAfterStanzaCount:10 orTimeout:5.0];

  [_xmppStreamManagement addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
  [_xmppStreamManagement activate:self.xmppStream];
  ```
- **After that i enable stream on xmpp Stream Did Authenticate delegate methods**

  ```
  // Check to see we resumed a previous session
  NSArray *stanzaIds = nil;
  if ([_xmppStreamManagement didResumeWithAckedStanzaIds:&stanzaIds serverResponse:NULL]){
  // Situation A
  }else {
  // Situation B
  //[self goOnline];
  [self.xmppStream sendElement:[XMPPPresence presence]]; // send available presence
  if ([sender supportsStreamManagement]) {
      [_xmppStreamManagement enableStreamManagementWithResumption:YES maxTimeout:0];
  }
  }
  ```
- **Please suggest me where & how, i resolve duplicate message repetition and also not call XMPPStreamManagement delegate Method's**

Answer (score 0):

To avoid message duplication, you should add uniqueness check on your end on message id. As every message packet contains unique id, so you should check that id to avoid duplicate messages.

```
<message from='userA@yourdomain.io' to='userB@yourdomain.io' id='msg_1'>
    <body>Shall we meet?</body>
</message>
```

Comment: Ok thanks but it's not my problem, I am working on that, I think I resolve approx 80% problem